# How to reference values within a different cell for conditional formatting over multiple columns

Tags: excel, matrix, formatting, conditional-statements

I am currently trying to write a rule for conditional formatting that will highlight the relevant cells if they show up within other referenced cells.

For eg. the data has 10 columns but I am only interested in highlighting the two cells in the same row from two of the columns if the values within them are both present within the referenced cells. These referenced cells are not part of the 10 columns and exist on a different sheet.

Essentially my logic is something like "if cellA exists inside reference cellA and cellB exists insde reference cellB then highlight cellA and cellB". Even if the whole row got highlighted that would still be sufficient for now.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Click the cell that you want to create a Conditional Formatting rule. (in this example I assume it's **A1**)

Then Create a **New Rule**
Then choose **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**

Then copy this formula: (I assume the Reference's worksheet name is **Sheet1** and your 10 column range is **B:K**)

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!B:K,A1)
```

Also don't forget to choose your conditional formatting type (colour, border shape ant etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you question in 2 different ways.

1) Highlight cells if the same row contains both of the data from the referenced cells:

Assuming your referenced cells are `A1` and `B1` in `Sheet1`,

- Select all the 10 columns in `Sheet2`
- In home tab, select conditional formatting --> new rule
- Select "Use formula to determine which cells to format"
- Enter the below formula in the formula box.

`=AND(COUNTIF(1:1,Sheet1!$A$1),COUNTIF(1:1,Sheet1!$B$1))`

- Select a fill color and press OK. This will highlight the row if both the values in referenced cells are present in the row.

2) Highlight cells if the cells contain either of the data in referenced cells.

Use the below formula,

`=OR(A1=Sheet1!$A$1,A1=Sheet1!$B$1)`

Let me know if you need any info.